# Load image name ussing session

Tags: java, ajax

I am doing some test, and I want to use java servlet session to remember the images that the user has already seen and to only print out the image names of the images that the user haven't already seen. For example, if the Images=2 I should only it should display img1.png, img2.png and if Images=3 it should only display img3.png because names img1.png, img2.png was already displayed. my code work, but I am not sure how the set the sessions so that I work like what I was expecting.

http://localhost:8080/XXXX/test?Images=3

```html
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
 
     res.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
           
            HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
     
            File imagePath=new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/images"));
            File[] imageFiles=imagePath.listFiles();
            
            
          String Imagesname=req.getParameter("Images");//geting Images from index.html
            int result = Integer.parseInt(Imagesname);  
       
           for (int i = 0; i < result; i++) {
              if(session.isNew()){

              out.print(imageFiles[i].getName());

              }else{
               out.print("welcome back");
             }
              
           }

   
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any ajax code here ???

Comment: Your snippet can't running, maybe you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
HttpSession httpSession = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();
httpSession.setAttribute("img","yourname");
```

Get

```
HttpSession httpSession = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(); 
String name = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("img");
```